# using model.save inside map

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
  const userAuth = await auth(context);
  const cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId: userAuth._id });

  const products = await Product.find({
    _id: cart.cartProducts.map((c) => c.productId),
  });

  cart.cartProducts.forEach((p) => {
    products.map(async (product) => {
      product.size = product.size.filter((size) => size !== +p.size);
      if (product.size.length < 1) {
        product.inStock = false;
      }
      await product.save();
    });
  });
```

Hello, This code is work very well and fitting my goals, the problem is I am getting an error in terminal which not shutting down my server or something but still an error.

error - `ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 62c1db576ff8ae0fde392c5d`

In order array sometimes there is 2 same products but with diferent sizes so it is updating them very well and everything works great, just getting that error .
Would like to get some hints, ty!

Comment: If you use two `for … of …` loops instead of `.forEach()` and `.map()` (which is used as if it's `forEach` in your case anyway) it will probably work.

Comment: Hi ty for your reply, I did change to 1 for of because cart is not iterable, but now I can't order two same products (with same sizes) , only 1 of them :( Ok I just fixed this! thank you so much!!